# Add a breakpoint when app asks for camera permissions

Tags: ios

My app is randomly asking me to enable camera permissions but I can't find which piece of code is causing it. I would like to put a breakpoint within my app so I can determine that. How can I do that?

Comment: can you post popup image?

Comment: What API do you use to access the camera? AVCaptureSession, image picker or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Before it happens, pause the app in the debugger (or set a breakpoint on your application entry point) and enter the following in the console:

```
breakpoint set -r '\[AVCaptureDevice .*\]$'
```

If it worked you'll see something like `Breakpoint 3: 302 locations.`

This set's a breakpoint on every method in `AVCaptureDevice` which will (hopefully) capture the trigger that's causing permissions to pop. If you're using Photos, use `PHPhotoLibrary`.

To avoid having to enter it every time you run the app if you need to trigger it a few times, set a breakpoint on app entry, right click on it, and Edit Breakpoint. Select `Add Action` and enter the above command to set up the breakpoints on each launch. Tick `Automatically continue after evaluating actions` to avoid getting interrupted.